# Cannot wear selected hat, nor can I see its name, which site I earned it on, etc,

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash, google-chrome, winter-bash-2022

I just came across a problem where you cannot wear a hat, nor see its name and which site you earned it on.

I am currently wearing a hat, but once I want to select a new hat, nothing happens. Image:

[image]

As you can see, now I am selecting the Unflagging hat, but I can't wear it.

Only change is that it shows the "Only on this site" checkbox, but:

- The hat doesn't appear on my avatar.
- I don't see the name of the hat.
- I don't see which site I earned this hat on.
- There isn't a "Show controls" checkbox.

All I see is a big empty space under my profile image.

---

Reproduced on Windows 10, Chrome Version 108.

Comment: No repro same OS and browser, so disable all extension and userscripts, including ublocks, adblocks and anything that block something, and try again, most likely it will work. (Something on your side is blocking something required for the hats.)

Comment: Wrong close reason. There is no changes in any system, anyone with the extension can most likely "reproduce" this bug. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by 3rd party applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out it was because of the Violentmonkey Chrome Extension.

Now it works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Now that's a really violent monkey. Hope you don't have the Lazyelephant extension! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Haha. Used this for StackExchange scripts.